# How to log an error after every certain number of tries during sleeping the thread?

Tags: java, while-loop, sleep

I have a while loop which checks `verifySystem` method to see whether it returns true or not. If it is not returning true then it will sleep for 5 minutes and then again calls `verifySystem` method after 5 minutes to see it returns true or not.

```
    while (!verifySystem(name, value)) {
        Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); // sleeping for 5 minutes
    }
```

So suppose for whatever reason, that method doesn't returns true, then my program will always keep on running forever..

So I am thinking to have a check like if it has sleep for atleast 10 times, then I would log an error using `System.out.println()` for now. I will use logger once I am intergrating my code..

How would I add this logic of 10 times check and if it has tried more than 10 times, then log an error and reset the counter.. So again it will start calling `verifySystem` method every 5 minutes to see whether that method is returning true or not..

In short, it will log an error after every 10 tries but it will reset the counter after that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int tryCounter = 0;
while (!verifySystem(name, value)) {
    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); // sleeping for 5 minutes
    tryCounter++
    if (tryCounter >= 10) {
        tryCounter = 0;
        // log your message here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jw23 for the help.. Make sense now.. Appreciated your help.. I also have one more question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976740/how-to-generate-alternate-color-of-balls-combination-for-3-boxes). See if you can help me out..

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
int errorCount = 0;

while (!verifySystem(name, value)) {
    if(++errorCount > 10) {
        // Log your message
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        // Reset counter
        errorCount = 0;
    }

    Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000); // sleeping for 5 minutes
}

errorCount = 0;
```